# Apache POI Cell Values are not appearing

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have the following code and the goal is to have Parking, Free, and Units going down in one column and the solid colors next to them. When I run it, however, I get the colors in the correct cells but no text to the left. I tried reordering the set statements but nothing is working.

```
CellStyle park=workbook.createCellStyle();
park.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
park.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
CellStyle free=workbook.createCellStyle();
free.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());
free.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
CellStyle unit=workbook.createCellStyle();
unit.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.ORANGE.getIndex());
unit.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
Sheet key=workbook.createSheet("Key");
Cell cell11=key.createRow(1).createCell(1);
cell11.setCellValue("Parking");
Cell cell21 = key.createRow(2).createCell(1);
cell21.setCellValue("Free");
Cell cell31 = key.createRow(3).createCell(1);
cell31.setCellValue("Units");
Cell cell12=key.createRow(1).createCell(2);
cell12.setCellStyle(park);
Cell cell22=key.createRow(2).createCell(2);
cell22.setCellStyle(free);
Cell cell32=key.createRow(3).createCell(2);
cell32.setCellStyle(unit);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating each row twice so probably the previous contents get overriden. Try reusing the same row:

```
// Cell styles
CellStyle park = workbook.createCellStyle();
park.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
park.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

CellStyle free = workbook.createCellStyle();
free.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());
free.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

CellStyle unit= workbook.createCellStyle();
unit.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.ORANGE.getIndex());
unit.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

Sheet key=workbook.createSheet("Key");

Row row = key.createRow(1);
Cell cell11 = row.createCell(1);
cell11.setCellValue("Parking");
Cell cell12 = row.createCell(2);
cell12.setCellStyle(park);

row = key.createRow(2);
Cell cell21 = row.createCell(1);
cell21.setCellValue("Free");
Cell cell22 = row.createCell(2);
cell22.setCellStyle(free);

row = key.createRow(3);
Cell cell31 = row.createCell(1);
cell31.setCellValue("Units");
Cell cell32 = row.createCell(2);
cell32.setCellStyle(unit);
```